# jQuery UI 1.8 and addClass / removeClass animation not working when in a timeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I have a page where I basically want an element to 'blink' for a certain amount of time and then go back to its initial state. Using jquery UI you can animate the addClass() and removeClass() methods:

```
 $this.addClass('success', 400);
```

and then

```
 setTimeout(function(){                 

     $this.removeClass('success', 400);

 }, 1000);
```

where the class 'success' has a

```
background-color: green
```

The first works. But the removeClass() inside the setTimeout simply removes the class without doing ANY animation. What can this be caused by?

Comment: Can you show how you are assigning `$this`? I've tested this and it seems fine. My code is slightly different than yours tho. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/BvupD/)

Comment: [Like the above, I too cannot replicate this.](http://jsfiddle.net/5dN6z/)

Comment: mmmh.... ok then it's gotta be a CSS conflict somewhere. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you'd use such a helpful method as [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) ?

```
$('button#test_add').click(function() {
    $('#content').addClass('success', 400);
});

$('button#test_remove').click(function() {
    $('#content').delay(1000).removeClass('success', 400);
});
```

And here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vT3KH/) to play with.

Comment: this is a better approach than directly touch `setTimeout`

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion of using delay instead of setTimeout!